# How to update Layout banner image based on path sent from the controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I've a view which includes radio buttons .. this view linked with a layout which has a banner image ...

**My question is how to update the banner image once the user check the radio.**

I've tried the following :

** The following code in the action method that will be called once the user checks the radio to retrieve the banner path then i store this path in viewbag :

```
 string bannerPath = MyEntity.MyTable.Find(selectedRadioID).BannerURL.ToString();
 ViewBag.Banner = bannerPath;
```

** In the layout i'm trying to read the viewbag value :

```
<img src="@ViewBag.Banner" />
```

** Pseudo code to get things clear :

// this function are called once the radio changed ...(it will return data through JSON to fill drop down list) :

```
function RadioOnchange() {   
   $.ajax({
   type: "post",
   url: "/MyController/MyMethod/",
   data: { sid: $('input[name="radio"]:checked').val() },
   datatype: "json",
   traditional: true,
   success: function (data) {
        var selectlist = "<select id='ddl'>";
        selectlist = selectlist + '<option value="">--Select--</option>';
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            selectlist = selectlist + '<option value=' + data[i].Value + '>' + data[i].Text + '</option>';
        }
        selectlist = selectlist + '</select>';
        $('#selectlist').html(selectlist);
    }
});}
```

// in my controller i have the following method :

```
public ActionResult MyMethod(string sid)
     {           
        sid = Convert.ToInt32(sid)
        ...
        ...    
         string bannerPath = MyEntity.MyTable.Find(sid).BannerURL.ToString();
        ViewBag.Banner = bannerPath ;                   
        return Json(dataReturnedToFillSelectList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

but the banner doesn't appear.

Comment: You should use ajax for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Viewbag is not accessible in JsonResult, so your action should return  more complex object:

```
public ActionResult MyMethod(string sid)
{
    ...
    return Json(new {
        BannerPath = bannerPath,
        Data = dataReturnedToFillSelectList
    });

}
```

then in your ajax success you can apply img src:

```
function RadioOnchange() {   
   $.ajax({
   ...
   success: function (data) {
        $('#banner').attr('src', data.BannerPath);

        var selectlist = "<select id='ddl'>";
        selectlist = selectlist + '<option value="">--Select--</option>';
        for (var i = 0; i < data.Data.length; i++) {
            ....
        }
        selectlist = selectlist + '</select>';
        $('#selectlist').html(selectlist);
    }
});}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the **[HttpPost]** verb before the method. Your AJAX call is of type Post but your method is Get.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyMethod(string sid)
{           
            sid = Convert.ToInt32(sid)
            ...
            ...    
             string bannerPath = MyEntity.MyTable.Find(sid).BannerURL.ToString();
            ViewBag.Banner = bannerPath ;                   
            return Json(dataReturnedToFillSelectList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```